# Full calendar scroll top when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Y6mqc/5/)

**CODE HTML:**

```js
   

     $(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
        
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        id: 999,
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
        
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>My Team</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            
            <div data-role="content">       
                <div id='calendar' style="width:100%;"></div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        
        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem that I have is:

When calendar is loading, scrolling is half. Look at the picture below to understand.

[image]

I want to start up the scroll bar

What is causing this problem?
I tried to use the following property `scrollTime: '12:00:00'` but does not work.

You can help me solve the problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine even without scrollTIme. (After I've added the agendaDay view). Maybe this code is incomplete or can you provide another screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using version one in your fiddle, scrollTime is not supported in version one of full calendar.

To use this feature you will have to use version two.

[Upgrading to version 2](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/)

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fexawif/edit?js,output) of it working with version two.

Update:
I have just realised in version one you can set firstHour.

```
firstHour: 0
```

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Y6mqc/7/) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

12:00 means noon time, use this instead:

```
scrollTime: '00:00'
```